# Netlify deployment

Tags: sass, dependencies, netlify, parceljs

I am trying to deploy a git repo on Netlify and I am using parcel in the project.

I am getting the error in the photo about conflicting local requirement.
This is how my `dependencies` and `devDependencies` look like:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
    "parcel": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.0.0-beta.3.1"
  }
}
```

and I am getting the error in the photo[image]

Any tip on how to resolve this ?? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved,
just had to remove parcel as a dependency!